# Swift ios7 storyboard - launch main scene myself

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, viewcontroller, scene

I want to control which scenes are visible myself from A to Z if possible.

I am new to iOS, but decided to go with using storyboard because it seems to be the direction things are heading.

From my own perspective, I am going to view it as a tool to design multiple scenes in one place, but I wan to control transiions in my own code. (I am porting from another language and tool that already manages and tracks logic flow itself)

That leads me to my question - I would prefer to load/choose my first/primary scene myself upon startup and "launch" it myself. How do I best do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could do that. For each storyboard you have an initial view controller and each view controller in storyboard has an unique identifier. Thus while creating object of view controller in the code you can just specify identifier of the view controller which you want to create.

First scene to be visible after splash screen is root view controller, which also you can create programatically and can be loaded from storyboard using identifier for that view controller. You can also load from storyboard without using any identifier, but in that case it would load initial view controller.

[image: Identifier]

You can set identifier for view controller like above in storyboard.

Comment: Currently I have two scenes in Main.storyboard - each with their own view controller "ViewControllerMainList" and  "ViewControllerMainGrid" - bith place in file "ViewControllermain.swift

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I am trying to go the route ak2g - i can't get it working currenlty, but assuming it will at some point - that solution will fit me excellent

Comment: Did you set identifier for you view controller in storyboard?

Comment: I believe I got it working now - I had actually tried storyboard ID as wel , but mistyped it there. Thanks everyone for helping, I will upvote everything I can :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make any view controller to show at first then just click your view controller in storyboardand click on is initial view controller

[image]

From Code (In AppDelegate)

Swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginSignupVC") as! UIViewController

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Objective C

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *viewController = // determine the initial view controller here and instantiate   it with [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:<storyboard id>];

self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks!

Comment: When I try to instantiateViewControllerWithIdenifier, the code/app just exits with "SIGABRT". My storyboard is called "Main,storyboard" so I inserted that as storyboard string. (Inspection during debug/step seems this was successfully rerieved.) The view controller class I want to instantiate is called "ViewControllerMainList" (which is placed in file "ViewControllermain.swift which in addition also contains class "ViewControllerMainGrid")